# Why isn't RandomAccess in the List hierarchy?

Tags: java, list, inheritance

`RandomAccess` is a marker interface in Java used by `List` implementations to indicate they have fast random access to their elements. Since it is designed specifically for `List` implementations, why is not in the `List` hierarchy? For example, consider the following method that requires a `RandomAccess` list as input and returns a random element:

```
public <E, L extends List<E> & RandomAccess> E getRandomElement(L list) {...}
```

I must pass this method either an anonymous list or a list with declared type `ArrayList<E>`, a concrete class, rather than a list declared with some interface like `List<E>`. However, if `RandomAccess` was parameterized and extended `List<E>`, then my method could look like:

```
public <E, L extends RandomAccess<E>> E getRandomElement(L list) {...}
```

and I could pass it a list with declared type `RandomAccess<E>`, which is an interface, rather than a concrete class. `ArrayList<E>` etc would just then implement `RandomAccess<E>`, rather than `List<E>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer might be in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) of `RandomAccess` (emphasis mine).

> Marker interface used by `List` implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access.  **The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists.**
>
> The best algorithms for manipulating random access lists (such as `ArrayList`) can produce quadratic behavior when applied to sequential access lists (such as `LinkedList`).  **Generic list algorithms are encouraged to check whether the given list is an `instanceof` this interface** before applying an algorithm that would provide poor performance if it were applied to a sequential access list, and to alter their behavior if necessary to guarantee acceptable performance.

It seems that they did not intend to add additional complexity to the collections class hierarchy but only offer an optimization opportunity to algorithms.

This does make some sense to me.  The user of an algorithm generally does not need to be concerned with implementation details.  Every algorithm that works on a `List` implementing `RandomAccess` will also work on a `List` that does not do so.  The only difference is performance.

Consider the following cases:

- There is no way to re-write an algorithm to be more efficient for `List`s that do not provide efficient random access.  (Or nobody felt like doing so yet.)  In this case, it will probably still be better to have a slow algorithm than none at all.  If the user needs the algorithm frequently, it should switch to a different `List` implementation.
- The algorithm can be re-written in two slightly different ways that each yield best performance for `List`s that do and do not support efficient random access.  Here, the user would generally prefer to simply put in the `List` and have the algorithm decide what version to use.  If overload resolution were used instead of run-time type introspection, a user might accidentally miss the optimized version if dealing with an abstract `List` type.  Having the caller check every time whether the `List` is an `instanceof` `RandomAccess` litters the code more than doing it once in the algorithm itself.  Finally, if an algorithm is later improved to support two versions, we need not go and alter client code.

Therefore, I think they did it they way they did it to actively *prevent* the interface being used as you wish to use it.  Of course, there will probably be legitimate uses that are negatively affected by this choice but it seems like a reasonable trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

Because `List` predates `RandomAccess` by a couple versions.

The `List` was interface was introduced in 1.2, and `RandomAccess` wasn't added until 1.4 (when the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) was introduced).  Rather than go back and change all the existing lists in the world, they just added a marker interface.

For more information about the design decisions, take a look at the [FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "change all the existing lists in the world"? The same lists that would have to be changed in my scenario had to be changed in actuality (ArrayList, CopyOnWriteArrayList, etc). I don't think any existing client code would break because of my proposal.

Comment: What method(s) would you expect to be defined in `RandomAccess` if it extended `List` instead of being a marker interface?  Currently, it's just a way of indicating that a given implementation of `List` has a certain behavior (that a for-loop using `list.get(i)` will run faster than one using `Iterator`).

Comment: @azurefrog I don't think that list.get(i) is faster than an iterator for RandomAccess, only that list.get(i) has about O(1) runtime.

Comment: Additionally, `ArrayList<E>` could not implement your hypothetical `RandomAccess<E>` *instead* of `List<E>`.  It doesn't directly implement `List`, but picks that up by extending `AbstractList` (not all of which support random access).

Comment: @azurefrog Java supports implementing a more specific interface in a subclass, so that would be no problem.

Comment: @JimmyT. According to the [documentation for `RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html), "a List implementation should implement this interface if, for typical instances of the class, this loop:

     `for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
         list.get(i);`
 
**runs faster than this loop:**
     `for (Iterator i=list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
         i.next();`" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @azurefrog I don't expect it to define any additional methods. It would still be a marker interface.

Answer (score -1):

Because a `List` could be a linked list, and a linked list does not provide fast random access. (Accessing the *k* th element takes O(*k*) time, and "fast" means constant time.)

Comment: OP meant that RandomAccess extends List. LinkedList would still implement List only.

Comment: Correct, `LinkedList` would still implement `List` only.